# Wordpress post query not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to figure out a way to make the_posts_pagination or any alternative output numeric post navigation for a custom query.

but it doesn't seem to work, I don't know if I am doing anything wrong would appreciate suggestions and solutions thanks in advance

My Code

```
<?php global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=3&order=ASC'); ?>

   <div class="main-post-loop">
        <div class="big-thum-section img-is-responsive">
           <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-block-thumb'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?> 
         </div>

        <div class="squiggle-post-meta-section clearfix">
           <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
             <div class="excerpt-post"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="continue-reading-section">
         <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="cont-reading"> Continue reading <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="squiggly-line"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_text' => esc_html( '&larr;' ),
            'next_text' => esc_html( '&rarr;' ),
            ) ); 
?>   
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that there are a few steps you need to do, first of all i suggest you use the [wp-pagenavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin, it handles lots of things for you.

Any way, i explain both ways, with and without the plugin,
first we write our query and set the `paged` attribute according to `paged` query var, so when the user navigates to for example page `3`, the query filters posts and shows the third page posts:

```
$paged = (int) ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ?: ( get_query_var( 'page' )?: 1 ) );
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged // This is important for pagination links to work
) );
```

Now if you have decided to use the `wp-pagenavi` plugin, it's quite easy to make paginations with custom queries, all you need to do is :

```
<?php if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) ); ?>
```

But if you wish to use [the_posts_pagination()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination) function, i'm not sure if it supports custom queries, but since it's using the [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function , it should work with this arguments

```
$args = array(
    'current' => max( 1, $paged ), // $paged is what we defined earlier or you can use just get_query_var('paged')
    'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
)
```

if it doesn't, you can use the [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function itself with the same above arguments.

See also : [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119617/paginate-links-and-query-vars)

Comment: thanks @amin for your time, although the pagination didnt cme up, tried all the suggestion but to no avail

Comment: @NeonEmmanuel Test the number of posts in your query, the `$paged` variable, the `$my_query->max_num_pages`, ... to see if something is wrong, you can use `var_dump` to test your variables

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 12 ));
        if( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_title();?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="pagination"><?php my_pagination(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In your functions.php add,

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
    }
endif;
```

OR
Try this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/